# delete spam with mailenable

Tags: smtp, spam, email

I am using mailenable on my VPS server.

How can I set up mailenable to checking incoming emails to my server if they are spam or not and if so, delete them?

Comment: First hit on google was MailEnable-supplied documentation on how to do this. I'm inclined to believe you haven't researched this first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, when service providers/packages bundle MailEnable, it's with the "Standard" version which does not include any built-in content filtering capabilities. Its anti-spam functionality is limited to SMTP transactional white/black-list/IP processing, nothing that actually assesses email content itself. In order to perform spam filtering based on email content assessment, there are two possible approaches:

- MailEnable does open up an API/hook for add-ons to assess content during its routing/processing - look for 3rd party solutions that take advantage of this
- "Front-end" MailEnable with a anti-spam/virus relay/gateway solution that sits in front of MailEnable - maybe something like the GFI MailSecurity product

The MailEnable support forums have information on both approach, as the MailEnable folks have been extremely generous toward the folks who are making their livings off of MailEnable's free "Standard" product - they do not censor the free exchange of this type information across their forum.

Answer (score 4):

The question you asked cannot possibly be responded to in a reasonable amount of time. But not to worry, [the answers have already been written down](http://www.mailenable.com/references.asp) by the thoughtful people over at MailEnable.

What you have on your hands is a complex system that can be used for very dangerous things if not managed correctly. Please, for your sake, for my sake... for *everyone's* sake, take the time to learn about everything surrounding the email infrastructure.

Questions like this are fine to ask, but you have to know when and where to ask them. When should this question have been asked? Before you got a VPS with MailEnable. Where should it have been asked? At your desk, rhetorically, just moments before you decided to spend two weeks reading everything you could find about the product, SMTP and email in general.

Go in peace (and get a subscription to Safari Books).